# Computing or approximating $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \binom{N}{n} \log (\frac{n+1}{n})$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \binom{N}{n} \log (\frac{n+1}{n})$ when $N$ is large. Is there an asymptotic formula that tells me $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{f(N)} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \binom{N}{n} \log (\frac{n+1}{n})$ for some function $f(N)$?

Comment: Some heuristics using the De Moivre–Laplace theorem showed me that with $f(N)=N$ the limit is $\frac{7}{4}$. The limit is approached very slowly though. Showing at least that your sum is of order $N$ should not be hard.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the order is N^2. The central binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{N/2}$ is $\approx 4^N/\sqrt{\pi N}$. Taking logs, this gives one term of order $N-log(N)$. Adding up all coefficients between N/4 and 3N/4 this should add up to at least quadratic.

Comment: Numerics suggest that it is order $N$. Do not forget that binomials away from the central one are considerably smaller in size.

Comment: I simulated in Matlab. You are right. I wasn't taking into account the fact that log((n+1)/n) goes to zero as n grows large

Comment: I will take a closer look at this later. A more precise analysis of the error term in the De Moivre–Laplace approximation may alter the constant factor in front of $N$.

Comment: I'm writing a partial answer below. It is superlinear, but far from quadratic. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Stirling's formula
$$
\log \binom{N}{n} \!= n\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right) - (N - n)\log \left( {1 \!-\! \frac{n}{N}} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\log \left( { n\left( {1 \!-\! \frac{n}{N}} \right)} \right) + \mathcal{O}(1),
$$
provided $1\leq n \leq N-1$.
Now
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( {n\left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( { \frac{N}{4}} \right)\frac{1}{n}}  = \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N)
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\mathcal{O}(1)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  \le \mathcal{O}(1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\frac{1}{n}}  = \mathcal{O}(\log N).
$$
Also, using $\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)$,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {n\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} & = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)}  + \mathcal{O}(1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\frac{1}{n}\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)} \\ & = N + \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {(N - n)\log \left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \\ & = N\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)\frac{N}{n}\log \left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)}  + \mathcal{O}(1) \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)\frac{{N }}{{n^2 }}\log \left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)} \\ & = N\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)\frac{N}{n}\log \left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)}  + \mathcal{O}(1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\frac{1}{n}}  \\ & = N\int_0^1 {\frac{{(1 - x)\log (1 - x)}}{x}\mathrm{d}x}  + \mathcal{O}(1)+\mathcal{O}(\log N) = \left( {1 - \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}} \right)N + \mathcal{O}(\log N).
\end{align*}
Thus, in summary,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \binom{N}{n}\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}N + \mathcal{O} (\log^2 N).
$$
With a bit more work, you can improve the error term, for example, into
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \log^2 N +\mathcal{O} (\log N).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I'm confused about the step $$ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)}  + \mathcal{O}(1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\frac{1}{n}\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)}  = N + \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N).$$ Using Stirling, the first term is indeed $N + O(\log N)$. However, the second term (using Wolfram Alpha) is $O(1) \cdot \gamma_1 N + O(\log N)$, where $\gamma_1$ is Stieltjes' constant. Thus, it seems that the whole expression (using log(1+1/n) = 1/n - 1/2n^2 + O(1/n^3)) is $1 -\frac{\gamma_1}{2}$.

Comment: @Asterix WA is incorrect. Note that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{1}{n}\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right)}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{1}{n}\log N}  = \log N\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{1}{n}}  = \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N).
$$ The correct expression involving the Stieltjes constant would be $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\log n}}{n}}  = \frac{{\log ^2 N}}{2} + \gamma _1  + o(1).
$$ Btw, have you seen my answer to your other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4105771

Comment: Thanks. You are obviously correct (and I probably mistyped into Wolfram Alpha??). Yes, I saw the answer to my other question and I'm going through both.

Answer (score 1):

Just as empirical observation too long for a comment:

Looking at $g(N)$ for $N$ as powers of $2$ from $2^1$ to $2^{20}$ using R, if I have understood the calculation, gives these values:

```
sumlog <- function(N){ 
  n <- 1:N
  sum(lchoose(N, n) * log((n + 1) / n)) 
  }

N <- 2^(1:20)
thesesums <- numeric(length(N))
for (k in 1:length(N)){
  thesesums[k] <- sumlog(N[k])
  }
```

gives

```
thesesums
#  [1] 4.804530e-01 2.086214e+00 6.423738e+00 1.678422e+01 3.976525e+01
#  [6] 8.854539e+01 1.894584e+02 3.951519e+02 8.109081e+02 1.647282e+03
# [11] 3.325379e+03 6.687407e+03 1.341778e+04 2.688532e+04 5.382768e+04
# [16] 1.077202e+05 2.155134e+05 4.311085e+05 8.623079e+05 1.724716e+06
         
thesesums / N
#  [1] 0.2402265 0.5215535 0.8029673 1.0490136 1.2426639 1.3835218 1.4801434
#  [8] 1.5435623 1.5838049 1.6086739 1.6237203 1.6326677 1.6379124 1.6409496
# [15] 1.6426904 1.6436791 1.6442364 1.6445483 1.6447218 1.6448178
```

and an extrapolation of that last sequence suggests perhaps $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\dfrac{g(N)}{N} \approx 1.644934 \approx \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

```
thesesums - N * pi^2/6
#  [1]   -2.809415   -4.493522   -6.735734   -9.534728  -12.872644  -16.730387
#  [7]  -21.093203  -25.951178  -31.298131  -37.130376  -43.445780  -50.243131
# [13]  -57.521754  -65.281274  -73.521486  -82.242281  -91.443598 -101.125404
# [19] -111.287682 -121.930424
```

so this looks close, with the error using $g(N)\approx \frac{\pi^2}{6}N$ perhaps $O\big((\log N)^2\big)$ and suggesting $\frac{\pi^2}{6}N$ is a good upper bound

Comment: That is what I have just got using Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for $n \geq 1$

$$\frac{\log(2)}{n}\leq\log(1+\frac1{n})\leq\frac{\log(3)}{n}$$

So all you need is estimation for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log{N \choose n}}{n}$$

You can use next

$$ \frac{N^n}{n^n} \leq {N \choose n} < \frac{(eN)^n}{n^n}$$

giving

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{N^n}{n^{n+1}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log{N \choose n}}{n}<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(eN)^n}{n^{n+1}}$$

So all you need is an estimation for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(kN)^n}{n^{n+1}}, 1 \leq k < e $$

Easily switch to an integral first

$$ \int \frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}} dx$$

In order to get the estimation start from the opposite

$$ F(x) = \int \frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}} dx$$
$$ F'(x) = \frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}}$$

Take $F(x)=\frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}}g(x)$

Now differentiate and compare

$$\frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}}=\frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}}(g(x)(\log(a)-1-\log(x)-\frac1{x})+g'(x)$$
meaning it is the best to take

$$g(x)=\frac1{\log(a)-1-\log(x)-\frac1{x}}$$

which is giving

$$F(x)=\frac{a^x}{x^{x+1}(\log(a)-1-\log(x)-\frac1{x})}$$

From this you get

$$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac{(kN)^x}{x^{x+1}} dx \sim \frac{k^N}{N(\log(k)-1)-1}$$

Obviously $k$ cannot be $1$.

You can use the same idea with various other estimation for ${N \choose n}$. This is just an illustration.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a helpful direction. Just to be clear, I'm looking for  the sum of log binomial coefficients $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \binom{N}{n}$, not the sum of log fractions $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \frac{N}{n}$

Comment: Alex Peter, note that you are solving a different problem.

Comment: Also, $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{\log n}}{n}}  = \frac{{\log ^2 N}}{2} + \gamma _1  + o(1)
$$ and not $=-\gamma_1 N$.

Comment: @Gary From which planet have you come to the Earth?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but a helpful one to understand the asymptotic behavior. Write $g(N) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log \binom{N}{n} \log(\frac{n+1}{n}).$ Write $h(N) = g(N+1)-g(N)$ and note that $$h(N) =  \log \binom{N+1}{n+1} \log(\frac{N+2}{N+1})  + \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\log  \binom{N+1}{n} - \log \binom{N}{n}) \log \frac{n+1}{n} =$$
$$=  0 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\log \frac{\binom{N+1}{n}}{ \binom{N}{n}} ) \log \frac{n+1}{n} $$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log(\frac{N+1}{N+1-n})  \log \frac{n+1}{n} .$$

If $g(N)$ grew asymptotically linearly, then $h(N) \to \Omega(1)$. If $g(N)$ grew quadratically, then $h(N) \to \Omega(N)$.

I ran this through Mathematica and got
$$h(N) = \frac{\log ^2 \left(N^2 H_N+N H_N+H_N+N^3+N^2+\gamma  N+N \psi ^{(0)}(N+1)+2 \psi
   ^{(0)}(N+1)+2 \gamma \right)}{N+1}$$
where $\psi^{(0)}$ is the Digamma function. This seems to go to 0 as $N$ grows to infinity although Mathematica tells me it grows at a rate $\log^2(N)$. Either way, it seems $g(N)$ grows much slower than quadratic.

Comment: To simplify $h(N)$, you can use $\psi(N+1)=H_N-\gamma$.