# Asymptotic Value of $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log(1+1/n) \log (\sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{N}{m})$?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to compute the asymptotic value of $f(N) =  \sum_{n=1}^{N} [ \log(1+1/n) \cdot \log (\sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{N}{m})]$. There's an upper bound
$$f(N) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log(1+1/n) \log 2^N = N \log 2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log((1+1/n)) \leq N \log 2 \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = N \log N \cdot \log 2.$$

There's also a lower bound
$$f(N) \geq  \sum_{n=\frac{N}{2}}^{N} \log(1+1/n)  \log 2^{N-1} \approx (N-1) (\log(N)-\log(N/2)) \log 2 \approx (N-1) (\log 2)^2.$$

My questions are

1. Does $f(N)$ increase at a rate $N \log N$ or $N$?
2. Is there a function $g(N)$ such that $\lim_{N \to \infty} f(N)/g(N) = c$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: The important thing is that log of the sum is $\Theta(N)$ once $n=\Theta(N)$, but once that happens the other log becomes $\Theta(1/N)$ and so those $\Theta(N)$ terms are themselves $\Theta(1)$ and add up to only $\Theta(N)$. (This is more or less what you did to get your lower bound.) So the question is whether the terms up to say $N/2$ (round however you want) can be more than $\Theta(N)$. Your first bound caps it at $\Theta(N \log(N))$ but it is too blunt in the small $n$ regime to be accurate.

Comment: (Cont.) Basically you need to do something in the small $n$ regime that describes the competition between the decay of the first factor and the growth of the second. Maybe a quick-and-dirty way to do that would be to use $\sum_{m=0}^n {N \choose m} \sim 2^N \Phi \left ( \frac{2n-N}{\sqrt{N}} \right )$ and then exploit estimates on the standard normal CDF $\Phi$.

Comment: If I didn't make an error in my own calculation, using upper bounds on the standard normal CDF yields an approximate upper bound (i.e. a bound that holds if the normal approximation is an overestimate of the binomial) of the same order as your upper bound i.e. order $N\log(N)$, so it remains to see if you can get a lower bound any better than your given lower bound.

Comment: Should be fine, you just split the sum at a smaller value of $n$ and use the $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3}$ lower bound once that difference is $\Theta(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. What 1/x-1/x^3 lower bound are you referring to?

Comment: $\Phi(x) \geq \left ( \frac{1}{|x|} - \frac{1}{|x|^3} \right ) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ for $x<0$. (This inequality is of course useless for $x \geq -1$.)

Comment: Incidentally the other bound that I was using is the much simpler $\Phi(x) \leq e^{-x^2/2}$ for $x<0$. (There is another upper bound which is better for $x>(2\pi)^{-1/2}$ which is derived along the same lines as the above lower bound, but really what I cared about here was the $e^{-x^2/2}$ behavior anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ian's answer, we have
$$
\log \left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^n {\binom{N}{m}} } \right) = n\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right) - (N - n)\log \left( {1-\frac{n}{{N}}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(\log N).
$$
for $1 \leq n \leq N-1$. Now
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)\mathcal{O}(\log N)}  = \mathcal{O}(\log N)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\frac{1}{n}}  = \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N).
$$
I showed in my answer to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099634) that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} {\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)\left( {n\log \left( {\frac{N}{n}} \right) - (N - n)\log \left( {1 - \frac{n}{N}} \right)} \right)}  = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}N + \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N).
$$
Putting these together, shows that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)\log \left( {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^n {\binom{N}{m}} } \right)}  = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}N + \mathcal{O}(\log ^2 N)
$$
as $N\to +\infty$ (the term corresponding to $n=N$ on the left-hand side is $\mathcal{O}(1)$).

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but maybe in the right direction.

One way to solve this is to look at $h(N+1) = f(N+1)-f(N)$, and then compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(N) =\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} h(N+1)$.

Here $h(N+1) = \log(1+1/(N+1)) \log \sum_{m=0}^{N+1} \binom{N+1}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log(1+1/n)[ \log \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{N+1}{n} - \log \sum_{m=0}^{n} \binom{N}{n}]$.

The first term is $\log(1+\frac{1}{N+1}) \log 2^{N+1} = \log 2  \log((1+\frac{1}{N+1})^{N+1}) \to log 2  \cdot \log e = \log 2$ when $N$ is large.

I'm not so sure about the second term. When I compute it in Matlab it seems to be slightly above 1.

When I compute the original expression $f(N)/N$ into Matlab, I get a value around $\log 2 + 1$ which seems to support the conjecture that $\lim_{N \to \infty} h(N) = \log 2 + 1$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{f(N)}{N}= \log 2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds we have

$$2^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2N}} e^{-N g(n/N)} \leq \sum_{m=0}^n {N \choose m} \leq 2^N e^{-N g(n/N)}$$

where

$$g(p)=\log(2) + p \log(p) + (1-p) \log(1-p).$$

This holds for $n \leq N/2$. For larger $n$, the method used in your lower bound introduces at most a constant factor of error.

Thus

$$N \log(2) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2N) - N f(n/N) \leq \log \left ( \sum_{m=0}^n {N \choose m} \right ) \leq N \log(2) - N f(n/N).$$

Or more explicitly

$$n \log \left ( \frac{N}{n} \right ) + (N-n) \log \left ( \frac{N}{N-n} \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2N) \leq \log \left ( \sum_{m=0}^n {N \choose m} \right ) \leq n \log \left ( \frac{N}{n} \right ) + (N-n) \log \left ( \frac{N}{N-n} \right ).$$

So you can then obtain the bounds on the first half of the sum, call it $\tilde{f}(N)$, by using the simple estimate $x/2 \leq \log(1+x) \leq x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$):

$$\tilde{f}(N) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{2n} \left ( n \log \left ( \frac{N}{n} \right ) + (N-n) \log \left ( \frac{N}{N-n} \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2N) \right ) \\
\tilde{f}(N) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{n} \left ( n \log \left ( \frac{N}{n} \right ) + (N-n) \log \left ( \frac{N}{N-n} \right ) \right ).$$

As I said before, the second half of the sum is $\Theta(N)$ by your method, so I think this is sufficient to finish the problem. It is really just a matter of getting the asymptotics for $\sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \log(N/n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \frac{N-n}{n} \log \left ( \frac{N}{N-n} \right )$, which appear to both be $\Theta(N)$ though I am not totally confident on how to prove that for the latter case.

Comment: For the latter case, $\sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \frac{N-n}{n} \log (\frac{N}{N-n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\frac{N}{2}} (1-\frac{N}{n}) \log(1-\frac{n}{N})$. This is equal to  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\frac{N}{2}} \log(1-\frac{n}{N}) - \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \frac{N}{n} \log(1-\frac{n}{N})$. When $N$ is large, the second term converges to $\sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \log(e^{-1}) = -N/2.$ The first term is $\Theta(log N)$.

Comment: @Asterix Great, then we conclude that the whole thing is $\Theta(N)$.

Comment: @Asterix Never mind, I guess "the second term" means the actual sum without the minus sign in front.

Comment: Everything seems to be $O(N)$. Unless I'm missing something.

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\frac{N}{2}} \log (N/n)  = O(\log N)$

2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\frac{N}{2}} \frac{N-n}{n} \log(\frac{N}{N-n}) = O(N)$

So we conclude that the whole thing is O(N). Is that wrong?

Comment: @Asterix I had another comment objecting to your minus sign in $-N/2$ and removed it when I understood what you meant by "the second term". However there is a problem which is that $n$ in the sum can get comparable to $N$ so assuming $(1-n/N)^N \approx e^{-n}$ is not necessarily legitimate...but it is close enough to not spoil the $\Theta$ expression (it might change the constant factor).

Comment: To be a bit more explicit about what I mean by that, by Taylor expansion you can say $\log(1-n/N)$ for $n \leq N/2$ is $-n/N+h(n/N)(n/N)^2/2$ where $|h(n/N)| \leq 4$.